# Can someone explain this please?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
0    Ground out of 2
1         1 out of 3
2         1 out of 3
Name: Floor, dtype: object
```

I want to modify this data so that I can create two columns named first floor and max floor.

Looking at the first item as an example:

```
0    Ground out of 2
```

the first floor would be 0 and max floor would be 2 etc...

This is the code I have written to extract the first floor items:

```
first_floor = []
lower_floors = ['Ground','Basement]

for data in df.Floor:
  for char in lower_floors:
     if char in data:
        floor_location.append('0')

 else:
    floor_location.append(data[:2])
```

When I do this, I get the following output:

['0', 'Gr', '1 ', '1 ']

I am expecting

['0', '1 ', '1 ']

Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You loop is written in a wrong order.

But anyway, don't use a loop, rather use vectorial string extraction and `fillna`:

```
df['Floor'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or for more flexibility (Ground -> 0 ; Basement -> -1…):

```
(df['Floor'].str.extract('^(\w+)', expand=False)
            .replace({'Ground': 0, 'Basement': -1})
            .astype(int)
)
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
Name: Floor, dtype: int64
```

As list:

```
df['Floor'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0).astype(int).tolist()
```

output : `[0, 1, 1]`

Comment: Yes, NaN cannot be converted to integer like this. Use floats or `.convert_dtypes()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the indent of the else case is wrong. It should be:

```
first_floor = []
lower_floors = ['Ground','Basement']

for data in df.Floor:
  for char in lower_floors:
     if char in data:
        floor_location.append('0')

     else:
        floor_location.append(data[:2])
```

And second, as you are looping through the Floor column, `data` will be just a cell, not a row. So `data[:2]` will cut the cell to 2 characters. This is why you see `Gr`.